# Storing and retriving timestamp with timezone via Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, oracle11g

I'm working on struts 2 with Hibernate 3. My database is Oracle 11g. My application is running on a clustered environment and each node may run on different timezones. My requirement is to show time to user according to their browser timezone. So which is the best way to handle this situation, whether I should insert date with timsezone and get the time with browser timezone from oracle conversion or insert every timestamp as GMT/UTC and convert every time while showing it to user? Or else is there any other best way of doing it? Thanks in advance.